# Pandas - Recode variable based on value_counts() results

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'col2': [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 7]})
```

I try to recode values based on how often they appear in my dataset, here I want to relabel every value which occurs only once to "other". This is the desired output:

```
#desired
"col1": [1,1,1,2,2,"other", "other"]
```

I tried this but it did not work:

```
df["recoded"] = np.where(df["col1"].value_counts() > 1, df["col1"], "other")
```

My idea is to save the value counts and filter them and then loop over the result array, but this seems overly complicated. Is there an easy "pythonic/pandas" way to archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close - need [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for same length of Series like original `DataFrame`:

```
df["recoded"] = np.where(df["col1"].map(df["col1"].value_counts()) > 1, df["col1"], "other")
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with count values by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df["recoded"] = np.where(df.groupby('col1')["col1"].transform('size') > 1, 
                         df["col1"], 
                         "other")
```

If need check duplicates use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for return mask by all duplicates:

```
df["recoded"] = np.where(df["col1"].duplicated(keep=False), df["col1"], "other")
```

---

```
print (df)
0     1     1       1
1     1     3       1
2     1     2       1
3     2     4       2
4     2     6       2
5     3     5   other
6     4     7   other
```